# How to Populate Variables for Grafana Dashboard Template in Jsonnet

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, jsonnet

I'd like to deploy and manage many similar Grafana dashboards with jsonnet/grafonnet using a single template where variables are substituted in each dashboard instance.

A simplified example of my (not working) approach so far looks like this:

```
# main.jsonnet
(import 'template.json') {
  _config+:: {
    name: 'thing1',
  },
  metric:: {
    name: 'metric1',
  },
} +

(import 'template.json') {
  _config+:: {
    name: 'thing2',
  },
  metric:: {
    name: 'metric2',
  },
}
```

```
#template.json
local grafana = import 'github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib/grafonnet/grafana.libsonnet';
local prometheus = grafana.prometheus;
local dashboard = grafana.dashboard;
local graphPanel = grafana.graphPanel;

{
  grafanaDashboards+:: {
    local fileName = $._config.name + '.json',
    fileName:
      dashboard.new(
        '%(name)s Dashboard' % $._config.name,
      ).addPanel(
        grafana.text.new(
          title='%(name)s dashboard' % $.metric.name,
          content='Dashboard for metric ' + $.metric.name,
        ),
      )
  },
}
```

However when rendered this outputs only one dashboard with values of "thing2" "metric2".

What is the correct approach for a template like this?  I'm looking for multiple dashboards to be output like so...

dashboard1 - "thing1" "metric1"

dashboard2 - "thing2" metric2"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in `main.jsonnet` you're merging (`+`) `metric2` on top of `metric1` content, completely overriding it.

You need to create an explicit field for each of these (an array would also work, but it's more cumbersome to later handle it in jsonnet), then you can leverage `jsonnet -m <dir>` to create one file per each of these fields.

Putting all together:

#### main.jsonnet

```
// main.jsonnet
{
  'dash1.json': (import 'template.jsonnet') {
    _config+:: {
      name: 'thing1',
    },
    metric:: {
      name: 'metric1',
    },
  }.grafanaDashboards,

  'dash2.json': (import 'template.jsonnet') {
    _config+:: {
      name: 'thing2',
    },
    metric:: {
      name: 'metric2',
    },
  }.grafanaDashboards,
}
```

#### template.jsonnet

Diff: adding required `gridPos` to that function call

```
//template.json
local grafana = import 'github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib/grafonnet/grafana.libsonnet';
local prometheus = grafana.prometheus;
local dashboard = grafana.dashboard;
local graphPanel = grafana.graphPanel;

{
  grafanaDashboards+:: {
    local fileName = $._config.name + '.json',
    fileName:
      dashboard.new(
        '%(name)s Dashboard' % $._config.name,
      ).addPanel(
        grafana.text.new(
          title='%(name)s dashboard' % $.metric.name,
          content='Dashboard for metric ' + $.metric.name,
        ),
        gridPos=0  // required parameter, put 0 but dunno if ok
      ),
  },
}
```

#### CLI

Using [jsonnet-bundler](https://github.com/jsonnet-bundler/jsonnet-bundler) to vendor imported dependencies

```
# Download deps to vendor/
$ jb init
$ jb install https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib
GET https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib/archive/3082bfca110166cd69533fa3c0875fdb1b68c329.tar.gz 200

# Create dash{1,2}.json output from main.jsonnet fields
$ jsonnet -J vendor -m . main.jsonnet
./dash1.json
./dash2.json
```